# Post-hoc test for mixed effect model adjusting p-values

Tags: mixed-model, post-hoc

We are performing post-hoc test(s) on a mixed effects model for repeated measurements in R (`nmle` and `emmeans` package). For subgroup analysis we include interaction `time_point * group`, i.e.

```
model = lme(val ~ time_point * group, 
            random = ~1 | ID, 
            correlation = corCompSymm(),
            data = data)
```

When we look at the marginal means for different groups over time we see (at least visually) some effect.

[image]

We would like to assess if there is a significant difference in response between the groups at each time point. Does it make sense to look at all combinations by

```
pairs(emmeans(model, ~ group * time_point))
```

and report adjusted p-values (Tukey)? This gives too many comparison and inflates potentially the p-values. Or does it make more sense to reduce the comparisons with e.g.

```
pairs(emmeans(model, ~ group | time_point), adjust = "none")
```

and then correct all 12 (4 time points and 3 groups) p-values with e.g. Bonferroni method?

Comment: Please include a semivariogram plot to check the correlation structure assumptions you are making.

Comment: Good point. Indeed, I'll deal with correlation structure later, but yes there is a slight slope from 0.8 to approx 1.2

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest

```
test(pairs(emmeans(model, ~ group | time_point)), cross.adjust = "bonf")
```

This uses the default Tukey method to adjust each set, then the Bonferroni adjustment to further adjust those adjusted P values. This will be less conservative. See the help page for `summary.emmGrid`

Comment: Thanks. However, I argue that this is more conservative than adjusting on 12 unadjusted p-values. But nice idea

Comment: @JJR Not true. Please see the last example for `emmeans::summary.emmGrid`. It shows larger adjusted P values when all are Bonferroni-adjusted than with cross-adjustments of the Tukey-adjusted P values.

Comment: You are right, the documentation says so. Your response has been again very helpful. However, in my specific case, I cannot confirm the documentation. Also, I don't want to hunt p-values, but clarify which approach is theoretically more adequate.

Comment: @JJR If you have 4 families of 3 means, and you use the Tukey HSD to test all pairwise comparisons in each family, then you are controlling each family wise error rate at a specified alpha. But you have 4 families, so, by the Bonferroni inequality, the chance of committing a type 1 error somewhere among those comparisons is at most 4*alpha. So if you quadruple the Tukey-adjusted  P values, that's a conservative adjustment for the super-family of all 12 tests.

Comment: +1 @Russ Yes, you are correct. Thank you!